# Rails 4 - manipulate form input and display in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a page where I take input from a form and then display it in a view.

**View:**

```
<%= form_tag("/page", method:"get") do %>
<%= text_area_tag(:x, @input)%>
<%= submit_tag("Submit Form") %> <%end%> 
<%=@input%>
```

**Controller:**

```
def myMethod
if params[:x].present?
    @input = "#{params[:x]}"
end
```

This works fine however I want to be able to identify where there are spaces in the string and then replace the spaces with a new line, and add a ",". For example, if the user inputs ‘cat dog mouse’ i want the view to return:

```
 'cat', 
 'dog',
 'mouse',
```

Is there an easy way to do this with a ruby function or will I need to write a regular expressions text search?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `gsub` will do:

```
"cat dog mouse".gsub(" ", ",\n")
```

This will replace every occurrence of a space  with a comma/newline `,`.

**Update**

Since you want to encapsulate each line with single quotes, a simple way to do it would be:

```
"cat dog mouse".split               # Split the string into an array (automatically splits by space)
               .map{|w| "'#{w}'"}}  # Reassemble it with single quotes added
               .join(",\n")         # Convert the array into a string again and insert the comma/newline characters between each entry
```

That code, of course, can all be written on one line.

*Here's another quick way to do this:*

```
string = "cat dog mouse"
new_string = "'" + string.split.join("',\n'") + "'"  # Outputs the same as above. Less friendly to read, but is also shorter.
```

Comment: Thanks @wes - i have updated my question, i also need each item to have be wrapped in single quotes. how would you do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use split, map and join:

```
"cat dog mouse".split(" ").map {|a| "'#{a}',\n"}.join
```

**split** creates a list `["cat", "dog", "mouse"]`

**map** transforms it `["'cat',\n", "'dog',\n", "'mouse',\n"]`

**join** creates a string again `"'cat',\n'dog',\n'mouse',\n"`